# Save wordpress passwords/logins to another database at the same time on registration?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, passwords

A client im working for has created a web app that uses a password and user name to sync data to a cloud. He wants a website to sell the web app through and serve as a support forum for this i was thinking of using wordpress with buddypress and the marketpress plugin from WPMUdev. We'd love to be able to sync the user names and passwords so that they're the same on the support forum and when they sync their data to the cloud.

So what we would need to do is store the password and username in another database table that the app can access or find a way for the app to access password and username tables within the wordpress database. I cant really find any pages in the wordpress docs or elsewhere that detail how passwords and usernames are stored on registration. Has anyone tried/done this before? Or does anyone know where i can find some information on the process wordpress goes through to store and retrieve passwords?

Cheers,
Jonny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by replacing the Wordpress default register screen with a custom one developed in the theme by a template for explample.

You can then use the wp_insert_user/wp_create_user function to register the user and in the same time to insert the details in the other database